# Windows shortcut that accepts hyperlinks dragged and dropped from a browser

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts, hyperlink, drag-and-drop

I want to create a shortcut on my Windows 10 desktop or an area on the taskbar that would serve as a drop target for hyperlinks dragged from a web browser. For instance, I want to drag the icon to the left from the address bar and drop it onto the area on the desktop or on the taskbar and that should launch a shell command with the URL as a command line argument. I tried to create a regular shortcut on Desktop, but it only accepts files, not hyperlinks.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. The receiver would (I think) need to be a folder. I tested what you want and it does not work.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on exactly what it is you're trying to do, and what the purpose is if poss. Maybe give us an example shell command including the URL? Then perhaps we can try to come up with some ideas.

Comment: Also it's worth keeping in mind that drag dropping from the web browser address bar creates a .url file that contains the URL plus some additional defining text. You can see this by opening a .url file in notepad to understand what text you will need to omit in your script parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one (contrived, but working) way to do it:

- Create a folder on the desktop, on which you will drop the hyperlinks. The dropped links will create .url files in this folder.
- Use a tool like RealTimeSync (part of [FreeFileSync](https://freefilesync.org/)) to monitor changes to this folder and trigger for example a batch script to process all added files.
- For each added .url file, read the URL from it, run your command and then delete the .url file.

---

Doing this in .bat scripts is a royal PITA (dealing with spaces and quotes), but I got it working in the end:

###### scan.bat

```
@echo off
cd /D "%~dp0"
for %%f in (%userprofile%\Desktop\Links\*.url) do (
  call process.bat "%%f"
  del "%%f"
)
```

###### process.bat

```
@echo off
echo Processing "%~1"
for /f "delims= usebackq" %%l in ("%~1") do set "_line=%%l"
set "_url=%_line:~4%"
echo Found URL: "%_url%"
start "" "%_url%"
echo.
```

The line with `start` in process.bat runs whatever command you want. In this example, it just does "run" on the URL, opening it in the default browser.